# Visual diff patch editor

Tags: git, diff, github, merge

Looking for some editor for complex Git merge commits.
Is there some editor where you can work with patch, edit all files at once, move changed blocks, etc.
Thinking about interactive diff2html:

- add possibility to edit whole patch/items and auto-update results
- edit patch items like change destination (+/- buttons, shortcuts or even dragging)

Simply replace merge and edit by editting patch to get final merge result you want.
"No" need to review or adjust after such a extended merge + have patch or commit you can save or reapply next time on similar code versions, etc.

Or another example - imagine github pull request fully editable.
Having ability to adjust changes - expand before/after, edit anything anywhere, etc. and save patch or apply results somehow...

Maybe similar to [Linux Text editor with integrated diff](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/46787/linux-text-editor-with-integrated-diff), but seems like Eclipse is a huge "workaround". And reinvent wheel may not be the best way (start from scratch).

Asked also here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70640721/visual-diff-patch-editor to show a demo snippet.

Comment: Added simple HTML page supporting drag & drop patch file and processing its content, result is JSON and another patch which does not include diffs same after apply left and right functions (lower case & whitespace unify in this example).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485714/how-to-edit-a-diff-patch-file-cleanly-are-there-any-patch-file-editors looks similar

Comment: https://meldmerge.org/ or https://github.com/timbrel/GitSavvy looks interesting...